# octave error: stem: inconsistent sizes for X and Y

Tags: octave

I am going to compute a discrete-time Fourier transform and I am using fft() and fftshift(). However, I got some error and I don't know why.

Here is my coding.

```
t = 0:0.005:0.595; 
n = t/0.005;
x = 4*cos(10*pi*t+0.25*pi) + 2*sin(20*pi*t) ;
xlim([0 0.595])
subplot(211) ; plot(t,x)
subplot(212) ; stem(n,x)


X = fft(x)/length(x);

f =-100:100:120;            
P = angle(X).*(abs(X)>0.001);
subplot(211); stem(f,fftshift(abs(X)),'.')
subplot(212); stem(f,fftshift(P),'.')
```

And here is the error I got.

```
>> LAB4

error: stem: inconsistent sizes for X and Y
error: called from
    __stem__>check_stem_arg at line 278 column 11
    __stem__ at line 37 column 49
    stem at line 127 column 8
    LAB4 at line 13 column 15
>>
```

Comment: `f` in your script is a 1x3 vector. Everything else is 1x120. I'm not sure what values you were actually trying to get in `f`, but it appears your step is incorrect.